# Why is Firefox not connecting to Facebook?

Tags: firefox, facebook

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (bionic), which I newly installed yesterday (June 26 2020) and the Firefox version is 77.0.1. I get a "Problem Loading Page" message on the browser tab heading and a page with the error message:

> #### The page isn’t redirecting properly.
>
> An error occurred during a connection to [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com).
>
> - This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
>   accept cookies.

Other websites connect fine (YouTube, Twitter, Wikipedia, Instagram).

I used the Firefox on my Windows drive and Facebook connects using that but I think that is an older version of Firefox since I have not updated it for several months.

The Ubuntu system overall has been running fairly slow, even though it is installed on a new SSD.

Comment: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/facebook-not-work-firefox-52757.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear Firefox's cache.

Mozilla has published a guide on how to do it: [How to clear the Firefox cache](https://mzl.la/18byRQJ)

Comment: Strange that this was the problem, since I had installed Ubuntu just the previous day. Still, it seems to be what fixed it. Facebook connected first try right after I cleared the cache.